# I've a column in my pandas dataframe where it contains arithmetic operator (*) as well

Tags: pandas

[image: here is the link to the image]

The data type of the column in a pandas dataframe is object. It contains an arithmetic expression, for example: 24 * 365. I would like to get the result (24 * 365 = 8760) of the expression returned in place of the expression. Can anyone help in resolving this?

The quantity column in the picture shown is having number of units multiplied by the quantity of each unit. I would like to get the total quantity by multiplying them.

Comment: `pd.eval` after replacing `X` with `*`, example: `pd.eval(pd.Series(['1 X 3']).str.replace('X','*'))` returns `3`

Answer (score 0):

Search for strings that contain ' x ' and split based based off that, convert to a number and multiply the left of the split by the right of that split.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Quantity' : ['1', '1000', '24 x 13.75', '60 x 40', '750']})
df['Quantity1'] = np.where((df['Quantity'].str.contains(' x ')),
                           pd.to_numeric(df['Quantity'].str.split(' x ').str[0]) * pd.to_numeric(df['Quantity'].str.split(' x ').str[1]),
                           df['Quantity']).astype(float)
df
#If above doesn't work then delete `.astype(float)` and there may be some additional logic to consider like what if there is a cell in this format 12.25 * 43 * 1 OR what about 40 / 8, or what if there is a capital 'X', etc.
```

ouput:

```
    Quantity    Quantity1
0   1           1.0
1   1000        1000.0
2   24 x 13.75  330.0
3   60 x 40     2400.0
4   750         750.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inter_m=df["a1"].str.split("*",expand=True).astype('int32')
```

Split the column by the symbol * . Later convert the numbers to type integer. Store in intermediate dataframe.

```
df["a1"]=inter_m[0] * inter_m[1]
```

Multiply the two columns in the intermediate dataframe.